# I tried the below code to get field value from a page(node) but it is returning null

Tags: php, drupal-8

I tried the below code to get the value of a field from my page node, but im not getting the value, instead its returning null. Where am i wrong?

```
$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
  if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
    $nid = $node->id();
    $node = node_load($nid);
    $datalayer['taxonomyfield'] = $node->get('field_taxonomy')->value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
$node->get('field_taxonomy')->getValue()
```

This handles multi-value and entity reference fields.

Here's a similar question/answer.

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/190107/75082